# Worksheet_change Event not firing after a while

Tags: excel, vba, target, worksheet

I've got this pretty simple Worksheet change event - which used to work just fine, in a book with lots of other code. I use it to format a range adjacent to a pivot table in the color scheme of said table.

Now all of a sudden, the code is only firing for a while, whence the book is open. Only a closing the Excel 2010 instance seems to fix the problem.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim EndRow As Integer
Dim StartRange As Range

Set StartRange = ActiveCell

EndRow = Sheet8.Range("A7:A9999").Find(vbNullString, , xlValues).Row

If IsNumeric(EndRow) Then

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        With Sheet8
           .Range("AC8:AO9999").ClearFormats
           .Range("C7:O" & EndRow - 1).Copy
           .Range("AC7:AO" & EndRow - 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
        End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    StartRange.Select
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the code into a public subroutine? And then calling the sub from the worksheet change event? Example: Make a new public variable called "TargetR", set it to Target in the private sub, then copy-paste everything to a new sub named NewSub. Your private sub would simply set TargetR, and then call NewSub.

Comment: Another potential issue I see is the paste special statement referencing xlvalues, which ought not need to be enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for commenting on this apparently unsexy issue here on se. I've tried that now, yet it doesn't seem to change anything. The event isn't executing at all thus whether it executes the code directly or in another sub isn't changing behaviour. Your second point isn't really clear to me. Do you mean xlPasteFormats? I've never come to terms with attribute/parameter naming in VBA but that part works like a charm that way...

Comment: I'll take another look at the code on my computer, and try and replicate the problem. In the meantime, the pastespecial observation simply means that you don't have to enclose xlPasteFormats in parentheses. It would look like this:  **.Range("AC7:AO" & EndRow - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats**. You don't need to enclose parameters unless they're not on the right side of an equals sign.

Comment: I agree that it's probably not the cause of the issue. Just an FYI.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I believe I'm running isn't memory issues somewhere. My solution was to rewrite the whole book, so you needn't bother.